# Extract max and min from a list of numbers in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a vector of lists that roughly resembles the following `tibble`:

```
library(tidyverse)

z <- tribble(
  ~x,
  c("65", "80", "101"),
  c("70", "83", "92"),
  c("65", "55", "84"),
  c("30", "70", "101"),
  c("82", "66", "55")
)
```

I would like to use `regex` and the `tidyverse` to keep/extract only the max and min values. This is all I have so far:

```
z %>%
  mutate(x = str_extract_all(x, "(max regex) | (min regex)"))
```

Comment: what you are looking for is `z%>%mutate(y = map(x,range))%>%pull(y)`

Comment: What's the output you want?

Comment: Sorry, the vector of list doubles was meant to be a vector of list characters and I was using regex. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need the same `type` after extraction, convert the `character` vector to `numeric`, extract the `range` of values and reconvert it to `character` while looping over the `list` with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
z %>%
      mutate(x = map(x, ~ as.character(range(as.numeric(.x)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but works:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~x,
  c(65, 80, 101),
  c(70, 83, 92),
  c(65, 55, 84),
  c(30, 70, 101),
  c(82, 66, 55)
)

df %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  unchop(x) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(max = max(x),
         min = min(x)) %>%
         chop(x)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   row [5]
#>     row   max   min x        
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     1   101    65 <dbl [3]>
#> 2     2    92    70 <dbl [3]>
#> 3     3    84    55 <dbl [3]>
#> 4     4   101    30 <dbl [3]>
#> 5     5    82    55 <dbl [3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>